# Is it possible create an HTML5 mobile game without the user having internet connection?

Tags: html5

I trying to make a app for the Play Store and App Store. My app will be 2D, but will have 3D effects. Is it possible to program it in HTML5 without the user having internet connection? Also, are there any good tutorials on HTML5? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you mean HTML5 only or HTML5 + an HTML5 framework like phonegap?

Comment: Just HTML5, I am not sure how to use framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory with HTML5 you get what you need to code what you want to do, but you can't create an app with just a pure HTML5 codebase, you need to interface your code with native code in a way or another. The real solution that can fit your case is using an HTML5 framework like [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/). It's the easiest and shortest way in your case.

Comment: Wait, can I build 3D structure with HTML5? And does phone gap take any profit percentage?

Comment: @CodingSeahawks yes you can build, in the end you will get a packaged app like the normal ones, phonegap translate calls to native code to HTML5. just read the wiki and the tutorials and you will be fine.

Comment: phonegap is free, there are also several plugins for phonegap, so you can still code in HTML5, if you do not find a phonegap feature that is right for you probably you can find a good plugin for that http://www.html5gamedevelopment.org/html5-tools/2012-01-webglgap-webgl-in-phonegap

Comment: Though do you know any great tutorials that teach the basics of HTML5 and graphic design?

Comment: @CodingSeahawks not real tutorials, you need to stick with the community of developers, the several blogs and coders that are trying new things and showing what they have done, it's a real big topic, especially if related with the design, but this is a really cool website http://www.smashingmagazine.com/search-results/?q=start+html5&cx=partner-pub-6779860845561969%3A5884617103&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8 and one of my favourite

Comment: Thanks! I am joining a coding club/class, but they aren't at HTML5 yet.

Comment: Although you can't get away with an absolutely pure JavaScript codebase, you can always make your app a webview that loads your HTML/JS/CSS and manage that per platform. PhoneGap is the better solution, but it's good to be thorough.

Answer (score 1):

You can in principle, create an offline HTML5 application, as descibed, for example, here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/#offline

This involves creating some manifest file, or something.

However, I've no idea what the platform support for this is like. You'll have to find out if it works for you.