# HTML5 as application for tablets?

Tags: javascript, html5, mobile

I'm looking at creating a tablet application (iPad, Nexus, Surface...). I've heard it's possible to create it using HTML5 canvas. I was wondering if it was limited to canvas, if div/input/table can also be used.

Can a normal HTML page be used as an application for the Apple, Microsoft, Android store?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible create an HTML5 mobile game without the user having internet connection?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/36083/is-it-possible-create-an-html5-mobile-game-without-the-user-having-internet-conn)

Comment: Added the javascript tag, because a HTML5 canvas is pretty useless without JS to draw on it.

Comment: Byte56's link is probably what you need. Simply creating an HTML5 app/site will still need to be hosted and it will not be installable via the Android store. You should look into phonegap (now Cordova) so you can deploy to more than a single OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around and with the comments, I learned that I need something to put a native front end over the html applications. There are a lot of different platform that support a lot of different systems (ex: Cordova).

Answer (score 1):

For the Android Store (Google Play), you will need a small portion of Java code.

To display the HTML in your application, you can use a WebView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html